# Deadlocks appeared after moving to MariaDB10.2 from MySQL5.5

Tags: mariadb, deadlock, mariadb-10.1

After moving to mariadb-server-10.2 from mysql5.5 I am facing deadlock issues. Please see the output of 'show full processlist'. Can someone give some suggestion?

```
| 162506 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:34163 | catalog | Query   | 1016 | update                       | INSERT INTO `sales_flat_quote_item` (`quote_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `product_id`, `store_id`, `is_virtual`, `sku`, `name`, `is_qty_decimal`, `weight`, `qty`, `product_type`, `base_cost`) VALUES ('6252710', '2017-09-08 07:38:14', '2017-09-08 07:38:14', '26601', '1', '1', 'c08236dbaf', 'Informaatika 8.c 2017/2018', '0', NULL, '1', 'virtual', NULL)                                                     |    0.000 |
| 162679 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:34380 | catalog | Query   | 1018 | Waiting for table level lock | DELETE FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE (store_id=1) AND (product_id IN ('26601'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |    0.000 |
| 162701 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:34410 | catalog | Query   | 1021 | Sending data                 | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 6656 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%informaatika%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)                                                                          |    0.000 |
| 162742 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:34456 | catalog | Query   | 1014 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 11474 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%Informaatika%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)                                        |    0.000 |
| 162892 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:34628 | catalog | Query   |  976 | update                       | INSERT INTO `report_viewed_product_index` (`visitor_id`,`customer_id`,`product_id`,`store_id`,`added_at`) VALUES ('8391969', NULL, '26601', '1', '2017-09-08 07:38:54') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visitor_id = VALUES(`visitor_id`), customer_id = VALUES(`customer_id`), product_id = VALUES(`product_id`), store_id = VALUES(`store_id`), added_at = VALUES(`added_at`)                                                  |    0.000 |
| 163286 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:35318 | catalog | Query   |  895 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33241 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%Informaatika%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%2017/2018%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`) |    0.000 |
| 163303 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:35337 | catalog | Query   |  891 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 11474 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%informaatika%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)                                        |    0.000 |
| 163783 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:35890 | catalog | Query   |  811 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 6656 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%informaatika%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)                                                                          |    0.000 |
| 163825 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:35952 | catalog | Query   |  804 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 33241 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%informaatika%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%2017/2018%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`) |    0.000 |
| 164314 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:36583 | catalog | Query   |  721 | Waiting for table level lock | INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` SELECT 11474 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%Informaatika%' OR `s`.`data_index` LIKE '%8.c%')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`)                                        |    0.000 |
| 165111 | catalog     | mymagentositexxxxxx.com:37633 | catalog | Sleep   |  557 |                              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |    0.000 |
```

The full output of 'show processlist' command is at [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/4c2d6bfe8b45bcf4fed60f225f251075/raw/377c5d129b50017612d70304c6c933deadbfbca7/mariadb_full_processlist).

catalog_sarch_fulltext uses MyISAM engine and all other tables using InnoDB engine. The creation SQL of table's are as below.

```
MariaDB [catalog]> SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogsearch_fulltext;
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
| catalogsearch_fulltext | CREATE TABLE `catalogsearch_fulltext` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  `data_index` longtext DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Data index',
  `fulltext_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fulltext_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_PRODUCT_ID_STORE_ID` (`product_id`,`store_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FTI_CATALOGSEARCH_FULLTEXT_DATA_INDEX` (`data_index`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=912741 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog search result table' |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [catalog]> SHOW CREATE TABLE catalogsearch_result;

| Table                | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |

| catalogsearch_result | CREATE TABLE `catalogsearch_result` (
  `query_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Query ID',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
  `relevance` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000 COMMENT 'Relevance',
  PRIMARY KEY (`query_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_ID` (`query_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_ID_CATALOGSEARCH_QUERY_QUERY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`query_id`) REFERENCES `catalogsearch_query` (`query_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATSRCH_RESULT_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog search result table' |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does setting some timeout values remove the deadlocks? Please suggest.
-Thanks

Comment: Those processes don't appear to be deadlocked, just waiting for a lock to clear.  Is your database killing processes as deadlock victims or is it just slow?

Answer (score 0):

If `catalogsearch_fulltext` is designed to use a `FULLTEXT` index, then you should be using `MATCH`, not `LIKE`.

If you do need `LIKE`, then there are two strikes against efficiency:  `OR` and leading wildcard.

What is the idea behind doing a search in `...fulltext`, then `INSERTing INTO ...result`.  Shouldn't you simply return the results to the user?  Or is this some dubious optimization of the 3rd party software that generated the query?

InnoDB has supported `FULLTEXT` since MariaDB 10.0.6; you should get away from MyISAM.  Note "Waiting for table level lock", which is what the queries is stuck on.  That comes from MyISAM, not InnoDB.

(No, I can't explain why you were not seeing these problems in MariaDB 5.5; perhaps there are other things that accidentally changed when you upgraded to 10.2.)